# Tracking when x number of events have fired

Tags: c#, events

Usually this is the stuff i would spend a few hours browsing google and stackoverflow for, however i ran into the problem of how the heck do i word this for a search engine.

I hoping there is a simple way of achieving this, as my current method feels far to "hackish"

What I need to do, if track when several sources of data have completed their loading, and only when all have completed do i load a new view (this is WPF mvvm). Now the data is loaded via a static class termed Repository each one creates a thread and ensure they only a single load operation can happen at once (to avoid multiple threads trying to load into the same collection), each of these classes fires an event called LoadingCompleted when they have finished loading.

I have a single location that loads a large portion of the data (for the first time, there are other locations where the data is reloaded however) what i planned was to hook into each repositories OnLoaded event, and keep track of which have already returned, and when one is returned, mark it as loaded and check to see if any remain. If none remain load the new view, else do nothing.

Something like this:

```
ShipmentRepository.LoadingComplete += ShipmentRepository_LoadingComplete;
ContainerRepository.LoadingComplete += ContainerRepository_LoadingComplete;

void ContainerRepository_LoadingComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           _containerLoaded = true;
           CheckLoaded();
}


void ShipmentRepository_LoadingComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           _shipmentsLoaded = true;
           CheckLoaded();
}

private void CheckLoaded()
{
    if(_shipmentsLoaded && _containersLoaded && _packagesLoaded)
    {
        LoadView();
    }
}
```

However as i mentioned this feels clumbsy and hackish, I was hoping there was a cleaner method of doing this.

Comment: you could use reactive extensions or implement a view model that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @Daniel A. White +1, you could Zip the events together. That would do the trick.

Comment: I would look into using Reactive Extensions and `Observable.FromEvent` to create three event streams and then perhaps somehow combine them together

Comment: If each load is it's own thread, have you considered using tasks and [WhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ok couple of new concepts for me here, Not heard of reactive extentions before, or these tasks, so i will look into both of these, @DanielA.White not sure what you mean by using propertyChanged, unless you mean having a loaded property on the Repositories, but wouldnt that be essentially the same as what i'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with Reactive Extensions and using `Observable.FromEventPattern` in conjunction with the `Observable.Zip` method. You should be able to do something like:

```
var shipmentRepositoryLoadingComplete = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler,EventArgs>(h => ShipmentRepository.LoadingComplete += h, h => ShipmentRepository.LoadingComplete -= h);
var containerRepositoryLoadingComplete = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(h => ContainerRepository.LoadingComplete += h, h => ContainerRepository.LoadingComplete -= h);
```

Then you subscibe to the observalbes like this:

```
 var subscription = Observable.Zip(shipmentRepositoryLoadingComplete, containerRepositoryLoadingComplete)
            .Subscribe(l => LoadView()));
```

The subscirption needs to stay alive, so you can save this as a private variable. When both complete events are invoked, the `LoadView` method should be called. Here is a working console example I used to test this method.

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace RxEventCombine
{
    class Program
    {
        public event EventHandler event1;
        public event EventHandler event2;
        public event EventHandler event3;

        public Program()
        {
            event1 += Event1Completed;
            event2 += Event2Completed;
            event3 += Event3Completed;
        }      

        public void Event1Completed(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event 1 completed");
        }

        public void Event2Completed(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event 2 completed");
        }

        public void Event3Completed(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event 3 completed");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();

            var event1Observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler,EventArgs>(h => program.event1 += h, h => program.event1 -= h);
            var event2Observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(h => program.event2 += h, h => program.event2 -= h);
            var event3Observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(h => program.event3 += h, h => program.event3 -= h);

            using (var subscription = Observable.Zip(event1Observable, event2Observable, event3Observable)
                .Subscribe(l => Console.WriteLine("All events completed")))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Invoke event 1");
                program.event1.Invoke(null, null);

                Console.WriteLine("Invoke event 2");
                program.event2.Invoke(null, null);

                Console.WriteLine("Invoke event 3");
                program.event3.Invoke(null, null);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Invoke event 1
Event 1 completed
Invoke event 2
Event 2 completed
Invoke event 3
Event 3 completed
All events completed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the shipments, containers and packages as asynchronous task then you have several options. As others suggested you can use `WhenAll` or `Join()` to wait for all threads to finish before proceeding. However, if your threads have to stay alive and the threads don't stop when they have finished loading, you can use the `System.Threading.CountdownEvent` as following:

**Edit**

Added how I would set up the threads and handle the events. Also moved the example from the static `Program` to an instance, more closely resembeling your situation. Again, if you do not need to do anything in the threads after they have loaded the data, just skip the `CountdownEvent` altogether and wait for all threads to finish. Much simpler, does not need events and can be achieved using `Join()` or in this case `Task.WaitAll()`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myWpfObject = new MyWpfObject();
    }        
}

public class MyWpfObject
{
    CountdownEvent countdownEvent;

    public MyWpfObject()
    {
        ShipmentRepository ShipmentRepository = new ShipmentRepository();
        ContainerRepository ContainerRepository = new ContainerRepository();
        PackageRepository PackageRepository = new PackageRepository();

        ShipmentRepository.LoadingComplete += Repository_LoadingComplete;
        ContainerRepository.LoadingComplete += Repository_LoadingComplete;
        PackageRepository.LoadingComplete += Repository_LoadingComplete;

        Task[] loadingTasks = new Task[] {
            new Task(ShipmentRepository.Load),
            new Task(ContainerRepository.Load),
            new Task(PackageRepository.Load)
        };

        countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(loadingTasks.Length);

        foreach (var task in loadingTasks)
            task.Start();

        // Wait till everything is loaded.
        countdownEvent.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Everything Loaded");

        //Wait till aditional tasks are completed.
        Task.WaitAll(loadingTasks);

        Console.WriteLine("Everything Completed");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public void Repository_LoadingComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        countdownEvent.Signal();
    }
}
```

And a mock Repository class:

```
public class ShipmentRepository
{
    public ShipmentRepository()
    {
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        //Simulate work
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        if (LoadingComplete != null)
            LoadingComplete(this, new EventArgs());

        Console.WriteLine("Finished loading shipments");

        DoAditionalWork();
    }

    private void DoAditionalWork()
    {
        //Do aditional work after everything is loaded
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished aditional shipment work");
    }

    public event EventHandler LoadingComplete;
}
```

Comment: That actually looks pretty clean, i didn't know about that CountDownEvent, Since all the threads are handled in separate classes this seems like a decent solution.

Comment: My problem with this seems to be because countDownEvent is locking the main thread, those event hooks are never handled.

Comment: Updated the awnser to include examples, if you still can not get it to work I will need more information about how you are starting your threads and hooking your events.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this: Add a property LoadingCompleted. For every instance you start a thread return that object to a list. On every loadcompleted set the property to true and in the place you catch the load completed loop through the list (myList.Any(x=>LoadingCompleted == false)) to figure out if everything is completed.

Not the most correct way to do it. But reading your scenario this might do the job.